# Input shape - How to feed metadata to a ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, dataset, preprocessing

I have data such as metadata: hospital layout, number of rooms, number of patients in a day etc.
and then I have data regarding the doctor’s check-ins. Which is more granular.
How do I feed this data to a ML model? I am worried that if I fit it as one dataframe where metadata data gets repeated per check-in data, they might affect the prediction and show as more important.
What is a suggested ways to feed type of data that consists of general unchanged information for a day, and data that changes almost every half an hour.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define what you can do with the data.

All the data might not be useful: ML learning models start being applied at a human level of understanding.

For instance, if you want to monitor patients, you have to define the objectives (ex: reduce costs in the hospital). Therefore, you need to know which kind of problem they have, the criticality level, the mean time spent, the treatment they need, the cost of using devices, etc.

This is only possible if you have all the necessary data.

So, the first thing to do is to define what are the objectives according to the available data. If no objective is useful, you will want to record new data to build a model reaching a useful objective.

Links:
https://github.com/masadeghi/EHRsample/blob/main/hospitalization_duration_prediction.ipynb

https://github.com/ajinkyalahade/Heart-Disease---Classifications-Machine-Learning-/blob/master/Heart_disease.ipynb

https://github.com/mhope321/HospitalReadmissions

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am analyzing amount of check ins a doctor can do in a day. So information regarding hospital layout is important, but also details about his check-ins (type of disease, patient info) would be important.

Comment: Do you want to improve the check-in management? 
Do you have access to the type of disease and patient info?
Do you know the outcome of the checkin? (= whether the analysis was correct or not)
Sorry, there are a lot of questions, but they are necessary to define the scope of the study or model.

Comment: No, I understand the intend of the questions. I mainly want to explain the reason some doctors do less check-ins in a day. The problem is regression, and it is supervised as I am working with historical records whose amounts of cases are already recorded. I have low level frequent data/ for every check in, the type of disease they’re there for, and high level data - number of doctors in a day, number of utilized beds etc.

Comment: Many early-stage data science projects are difficult because they were not data-driven in the first place. That's why the knowledge that could be extracted through models is limited. However, having some interesting results could help executives to improve the data collection. That's why you could start with robust models like random forest to detect interesting patterns and have a better understanding of the main processes. I've added some links that could be interesting for your project.